# What happens when you close an Entity Framework connection

Tags: entity-framework, database-connection, connection-pooling

We are using Entity Framework 1.0.

In some cases we need to explicitly open connections, and then need to explicitly close connections. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738582.aspx

My question is, when we call "close" does the connection actually get closed, or is it just returned to the connection pool?

Comment: can you explain why u are doing some custom connection management(performance?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No when you call close it will return to the pool.

If you want to "free" the pool aka term connections use [ClearAllPools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools(VS.80).aspx)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(VS.80).aspx) on connection pooling, it always helps when i reference that.